# Can you query for elements between multiple children in a parent-child join in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

Is it possible to query among the elements of children and return the parent. So if one child has a gender of male and age of 17 and another has a gender of female and age of 21. Is it possible to return the parents if and only if they have a male child and a child whose age is 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "age": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "gender": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "my_join_field": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "parents": "children"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

**Parent document -**

```
{
  "my_id": "1",
  "text": "This is parent 1",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "parents" 
  }
}
```

**Child documents -**
Both these documents are the child of same parent

```
{
  "my_id": "4",
  "age": 21,
  "gender": "female",
  "text": "This is second child",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "children",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}
{
  "my_id": "3",
  "age": 17,
  "gender": "male",
  "text": "This is first child",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "children",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "children",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "gender": "male"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "children",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "age": 21
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65677365",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "my_id": "1",
          "text": "This is parent 1",
          "my_join_field": {
            "name": "parents"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Aidan Tan did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @Aidan Tan if my answer helped you resolve your issue, can you please accept and upvote the answer 

Comment: thank you so much! Cannot believe this slipped my mind.

Comment: @AidanTan glad this worked for you :) Can you please upvote the answer as well :)